# How to aggregate event dates based on aggregated table?

Tags: sql

I have a table that aggregates disables/reenables events in the following format:

| Disabled Date | Enabled Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 01/01 | 5 |
| 01/01 | 02/01 | 2 |
| 03/01 | 05/01 | 1 |
| 04/01 | 05/01 | 5 |

and want to build a report that aggregates the number of disables and reenables per day:

| Date | Enables | Disables |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 5 | 7 |
| 02/01 | 2 | 0 |
| 03/01 | 0 | 1 |
| 04/01 | 0 | 5 |
| 05/01 | 6 | 0 |

I was able to build the following query that works for days that have at least one disable and one enable:

```sql
SELECT
  disables.disable_date AS disable_date, 
  disables.disable_count disable_count,
  enables.enable_count enable_count
FROM 
  (SELECT
    disable_date, 
    sum(disable_count) disable_count
    FROM table
  GROUP BY 1) AS disables,
    (SELECT
    enable_date, 
    sum(disable_count) enable_count
    FROM table
  GROUP BY 1) AS enables
WHERE enables.enable_date = disables.disable_date;
```

Any suggestions how to build the complete output? I'm not sure this is the right strategy, so a JOIN could also be considered.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running : mysql, sql-server, …?

Comment: It has to be agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT disabled_date AS Date,
                Sum(count)    AS Disables
         FROM   table1
         GROUP  BY disabled_date
         UNION ALL
         SELECT enabled_date AS Date,
                Sum(-count)  AS Disables
         FROM   table1
         GROUP  BY enabled_date)
SELECT cte.date,
       COALESCE(Sum(CASE
                      WHEN cte.disables > 0 THEN cte.disables
                    END), 0) AS Enables,
       COALESCE(Sum(CASE
                      WHEN cte.disables < 0 THEN -cte.disables
                    END), 0) AS Disables
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY cte.date
ORDER  BY cte.date;
```

### TEST

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13cace/3

Comment: Thanks! I didn't end up using COALESCE though, I had the first query of the select returning 0 for enables and the second returning 0 for disables and on the outer query I can just SUM them.